# Laravel sql insert is not working properly via DB::unprepared

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, mariadb

I get SQL via file_get_contents and give  DB::unprepared function

```
 $path = public_path('sql/Store.sql');
 $sql = file_get_contents($path);
 DB::unprepared($sql);
```

the tables are created but the triggers are not created.
But when I put this SQL code to phpMyadmin both tables and triggers are created successfully. I use **Server version: 10.3.28-MariaDB - MariaDB Server.**
Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried typing your sql in `unprepared()` instead of getting it from a file?

Comment: Yes , i got this error,

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TRIGGER `trig_categories_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `categories`

Comment: If  without triggers tables creating successfully

Answer (score 0):

You should trim the contents that come from the file to remove some characters like `\n` at the end of sqls. I've used `trim($file_path, "\x00..\x1F")` to remove this range of characters from your sql.

```
$path = public_path('sql/Store.sql');
$sql = trim(file_get_contents($path), "\x00..\x1F");
DB::unprepared($sql);
```

Comment: I got this error...
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TRIGGER `trig_categories_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `categories`

Comment: You have an error in your sql. It is a different question that should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: If I have an error in SQL how can it create via PHPMyAdmin??